# How to increase Sonar java heap size?

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I am analyzing quite a large project with Sonar. The first few runs went OK but now I get error. Something to do with timemachine and violation analyzer:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at 
org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.mapViolations(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:131)
    at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.decorate(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:70)
```

I execute Sonar using ANT. Can I increase the java heap size somehow?

Answer (score 4):

The Sonar ANT task executes as part of ANT so you need to set the JVM heap using the standard ANT environment parameter. For example:

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Xmx256m
```

Comment: hmm how do I do this within my Sonar Ant target?

Comment: @user1340582 No, JVM settings can only be changed from the command-line. ANT itself is a Java program, this is a Unix environment variable that ANT will use on start-up.

Comment: @user1340582 An alternative option is to analyse the code by calling the Sonar Java runner, using the "exec" task from ANT.